# The modulus operator (%) doesn't work for huge numbers

Tags: c#

So, to put it short, the modulus operator returns a false output when used with huge numbers. Please, help.

I thought that the problem might deal with the value types, so I tried converting everything to all types of int and also to double. I tried to use this (^) and Math.Pow().

```
int N = 10379
int S1 = 3701;
int d = 37;
int T1 = S1 ^ d % N;


double F = 10379
double S2 = 3701;
double e = 37;
double T2 = Math.Pow(S2, e) % F;
```

I expect the output to be 7770 as it should be, but I never get it.

Comment: `^` is XOR, not exponent.

Comment: Try `long` and `float`.

Comment: Are you sure the result is not too big for `int`? ( I did not check it myself )

Comment: Also, what does "never get it" mean? What *do* you get? Are you trying to compare the result to the literal 7770? Your `int` code example is incorrect and you should never try to compare a calculated `double` to an exact value.

Comment: @cornel.raiu Yes, it's too big, but the double should work and still it doesn't

Comment: @itsme86  I get some 3000 number. And yes, I know that int is incorrect, thanks

Comment: to add to what @itsme86 said, even if you raise 3701 to the 37th power the resulting number is WAY too big to store even in unsigned long. You will need to use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) and to raise to an exponent use [BigInteger.Pow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.pow?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: So can anyone post a code that will output 7770?

Comment: @Bobby user's already said what you should do; did you see Mr. Rollins post?

Comment: @Chris Rollins Thank you, I'll try right now

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ No, where is it?

Comment: @Bobby *And yes, I know that int is incorrect, thanks* When you post a [mcve] it should preferably illustrate the bug - and *only* the bug - that you're actually asking about. If you have other known bugs in the code, people might be confused and focus on those issues instead of the one you're actually asking about, or they might downvote or vote to close because they perceive the question as asking about too much at once (or not having a proper code sample).

Comment: @itsme86 and or -@Chris Rollins, you guys should have thrown an answer up for grabs as clearly your comments pointed out the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8). `int` or even `unsigned long` is way too small to hold the product. And calculating integer values with `double` is also problematic.

`BigInteger` has a static method [`ModPow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow?view=netframework-4.8) made exactly for your purpose:

```
int N = 10379
int S1 = 3701;
int d = 37;
BigInteger T1 = BigInteger.ModPow(S1, d, N); // 7770
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forget about `^` as this is a XOR operator not a power operator. You can multiply it using `for` loop for `d` times and apply `%` each time.

```
int i, T1;
T1 = 1;
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    T1 *= S1;
    T1 %= N;
}
```